# Two-sample test of difference in probability mass at the extremes of the empirical distributions

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, two-sample

I am running an experiment that will generate a dependent variable (DV) in two treatments, T1 and T2.

One of the hypotheses I want to test is whether the distribution of the DV in T1 has more mass at the extremes compared to T2.

So say my DV (discrete variable) is distributed on support $[0,100]$, I would be interested in testing

1. $\Pr(X_{T1}\leq 25)>\Pr(X_{T2}\leq 25)$ and $\Pr(75\leq X_{T1}\leq 100)>\Pr(75\leq X_{T2}\leq 100)$, jointly,
2. $\Pr(X_{T1}\leq 25)\neq\Pr(X_{T2}\leq 25)$,
3. $\Pr(75\leq X_{T1}\leq 100)\neq\Pr(75\leq X_{T2}\leq 100)$

$x$ in $Pr(X\leq x)$ will be determined by the empirical support of the DV, not the shape of the distribution. In this case it is the first and third quartile of the support.

Is there a known test for (some of) these? If not, how one would go about testing these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For #1, run a 2x2 table using a chi-squared test with the two columns representing T1 and T2 and the two rows representing $\leq 25$ and $>75$.  Table cell values are the number of counts that are below and above the cutpoints for the two treatments.  If the calculated chi-squared statistic >3.84, the extreme values are significantly different between the treatments.

For #2, that's merely a 1x2 chi-squared test with one row representing $\leq 25$ and the two columns representing T1 and T2.

For #3, ditto, just use >75 for the single row's characteristic.

Although the chi-squared test appears to be a test of count differences, what is formally being tested are the proportions.